# AssertionError: array([], dtype=int64) != array([], dtype=int64)

Tags: python, numpy, unit-testing

I am creating unit tests and I have a test case where the output is expected to be an empty numpy array. I have a second test case where I test the other expected array which has elements.

```
class myTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        var = 0
        result = myFunction(var)
        self.assertEqual(np.array([], dtype=np.int64), result)
```

> AssertionError: array([], dtype=int64) != array([], dtype=int64)

I have a feeling it's because they are both empty but I'm not sure. How should I do this test instead?

I ran a debugger to compare the two variables and this is what I got.

*result*

```
array([], dtype=int64)
special variables
[0:0] :[]
dtype:dtype('int64')
max:'array is empty'
min:'array is empty'
shape:(0,)
size:0
```

*np.array([], dtype=np.int64)*

```
array([], dtype=int64)
special variables
[0:0] :[]
dtype:dtype('int64')
max:'array is empty'
min:'array is empty'
shape:(0,)
size:0
```

Comment: I believe there's a `numpy` testing module or utility that has 'assertions' that are suitable for testing arrays.  As you see here, the regular Python assertions are not numpy aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it has to do with comparing equality of empty arrays.

> The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous.

If you look at the result of the comparison you can see that it's not a bool value:

```
>>> np.array([], dtype=np.int64) == np.array([], dtype=np.int64)
array([], dtype=bool)
```

Have you considered checking for length of the array instead/first?

Comment: Good point with the length instead. That solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python3 and care about the ordering of contents you can use [assertSequenceEqual()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertSequenceEqual)

Comment: I tried this but got a similar error ```AssertionError: Sequences differ: array([], dtype=float64) != array([], dtype=float64)```